# Count neighboring cells

Tags: java, function, for-loop

I don't understand what is wrong with this loop, it normaly would check the surrounding cells of (x,y).
When calling this function, there is only 4 passages in the loop and not 8
This is probably a stupid mistake but I cant see it !

```
private int countAliveNeighbors(int x, int y) {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = Math.max(0, x - 1); i < Math.min(grid.getWidth()-1, x + 1); i++) {
        for (int j = Math.max(0, y - 1); j < Math.min(grid.getHeight()-1, y + 1); j++) {
            if (!(i == x && j == y)) {
                if (grid.isAlive(i, j))
                    count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Comment: Several points: 1) usually stackoverflow is kind of against letting people to help you debug; 2) please give more context, like: when u call, what's the parameter passed in, and what's the specs of grid

Comment: What is the purpose of `-1` in `grid.getWidth()-1`?

Comment: I know about that but I'm going crazy with this function, I have been looking at it for half an hour !
This is a 2d array of cells 100*100

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your upper limit in your `for` statements should by checking for `<=` not just less-than.  By testing for less-than you stop before getting to `x+1` or `y+1`. It should look like this:

```
for (int i = Math.max(0, x - 1); i <= Math.min(grid.getWidth()-1, x + 1); i++) {
    for (int j = Math.max(0, y - 1); j <= Math.min(grid.getHeight()-1, y + 1); j++) {
```